# Max bandwidth of wireless access point with gigabit backhaul

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm looking at setting up a network with full WiFi coverage.

Right now I'm still comparing access points to mesh.

I see the options for AC access points offer wireless bandwidth in excess of 1Gbps. Like AC1200.

What I don't understand is how this is possible given the Ethernet backhaul is running at max 1000 Mbps.

I get that the total bandwidth is shared among all devices connected to that access point, and also between the 2.4 & 5 GHz bands.

Still, given that the AP can only send & receive data at the gigabit speed of the backhaul, the total bandwidth available to all clients must be limited to a gigabit?

Is there something I'm missing?

Because it seems pointless to get faster than 1000Mbps AC access points.

Comment: You may want to stream data (e.g. HD video) from several local devices to several local devices. That doesn't use the backhaul.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AC1200 is 5GHz at 867Mbps and 2.4GHz at 300Mbps - These numbers are actually 802.11ac rates and not really the actual throughout you can achieve.  So, if you run a performance test on 5GHz (867), you'll get a TCP throughput of ~400Mbps and if you run the same test on 2.4GHz (300), you'll get a TCP throughput of ~130Mbps - So, if you're in a clean room with no obstructions, you can achieve ~550Mbps which your 1000Mbps backend ethernet link will service with no issues.  Some Access Point vendors are adding 2.5Gbps ports on their Access Points with MuMiMo which requires higher backend bandwidth.